# How to remove option from bit wise operation

Tags: c#, bitwise-operators

I am working in a WPF app where I have some Items checked, I am trying to clear the checked items and reset it in the for loop if the is check is true. Using ' fruit.FruitType = NewFruitType.None;' after running the loop the selection is still NONE. If I remove' fruit.FruitType = NewFruitType.None;' it keeps all items and don't remove the Items that were unchecked.

Item1 | item2 | item3| item4

If item 3 and 4 are removed how can I have the selection be Item1 | item2?

```
 fruit.FruitType = NewFruitType.None;

 foreach (var fruitType in fruit.FruitTypes.Where(x => x.IsChecked))
 {
     contact.FruitType |= (NewFruitType)fruitType.Id;
 }
```

Comment: I cannot see what `.FruitType` and `.FruitTypes` on the fruit are. I cannot see what `.FruitType` on the contact is. I cannot see the declaration of the `NewFruitType` type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `AND` `NOT` (technically "and complement of") logic. In C# syntax that is `&=` and `~` for bitwise operations.

Try this:

```cs
var stuff = Items.Item1 | Items.Item2 | Items.Item3 | Items.Item4;
Console.WriteLine(stuff);

stuff &= ~Items.Item2; 
Console.WriteLine(stuff);
```

result:

```
Item1, Item2, Item3, Item4
Item1, Item3, Item4
```

If you wanted to remove multiple at once, you need to continue anding:

```cs
var stuff = Items.Item1 | Items.Item2 | Items.Item3 | Items.Item4;
Console.WriteLine(stuff);

stuff &= ~Items.Item2 & ~Items.Item3; 
Console.WriteLine(stuff);
```

result:

```
Item1, Item2, Item3, Item4
Item1, Item4
```

This should also work even if the initial list does not include the removed flags:

```cs
var stuff = Items.Item1 | Items.Item3 | Items.Item4;
Console.WriteLine(stuff);

stuff &= ~Items.Item2 & ~Items.Item3; 
Console.WriteLine(stuff);
```

result

```
Item1, Item3, Item4
Item1, Item4
```

Check out the details in Microsoft's reference here: [Bitwise and shift operators (C# reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/bitwise-and-shift-operators)

Comment: What if  Items.Item2 was not in the list to begin with is that fine?

Comment: @Dev Yes, that is fine. It should work just the same. I will update the answer to show that too.